# Голосование на ajax

Tags: ajax, php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

$(".vote").click(function() 
{
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var name = $(this).attr("name");
var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
var parent = $(this);

if(name=='plus')
{
$(this).fadeIn(200).html('<img src="/images/upload.gif" align="absmiddle">');
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/pages/up_vote.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html)
   {
    parent.html(html);
  }  });

}
else
{
$(this).fadeIn(200).html('<img src="/images/upload.gif" align="absmiddle">');
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/pages/down_vote.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html)
   {
       parent.html(html);
  }
 });
}
return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

---

```
echo '<span><a href="" class="vote" id="'.$rowcomments['id'].'" name="plus">+</a></span>';
```

---

И обработчик

---

```
require_once '../system/core.php';
if($_POST['id'])
{
if($row['id_user']==$user['id'] && $user['level']<2 && $articles['pobeda']==0)
{
echo 'Вы уже голосовали за данный комментарий! Голосовать можно только один раз!';
exit;
}
$articles = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `articles_comments` WHERE `id`='".$id."'"));
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `articles_comments_reputation` WHERE `id_comments`='".$id."'"));
mysql_query("UPDATE `articles_comments` SET `golosov` = '".intval($articles['golosov']-1)."' WHERE `id` = '".$articles['id']."'");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `articles_comments_reputation` SET `id_user` = '".$user['id']."', `id_articles` = '".$articles['id_articles']."', `id_comments` = '".$id."', `type` = 'minus', `time` = '".$realtime."'");
exit;
}
```

---

Проблема в том, что результат выводится после того, как обновлю страницу и, к тому же, почему-то прибавляется/отнимается сразу 2 голоса.
Может кто-нибудь помочь?

Comment: каким образом подгружается js? проверьте содержимое 

            intval($articles['golosov']-1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Присаживайтесь поудобнее - писать буду много ))

**-** Для начала, есть один вопрос:

```
// Откуда берется переменная $id? Например, тут:
SELECT * FROM `articles_comments` WHERE `id`='".$id."'
// Что-то вроде - $id = $_POST['id']; - выше по коду, я не увидел
```

**-** Зато, бросилось в глаза то, что вы используете в сравнении переменную **$row['id_user']** до того, как получаете результат в **$row** из запроса к БД:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `articles_comments_reputation` WHERE `id_comments`='".$id."'"));
```

Тоже самое могу сказать о проверке, с использованием переменной **$articles['pobeda']**

**-** Абсолютной загадкой осталося для меня запрос

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `articles_comments_reputation` WHERE `id_comments`='".$id."'"));
```

и чудесное явление переменной **$realtime**, хотя последняя может браться из файла **core.php**

**-** Далее... Исходя из того, что есть проверка переменной **name** (в JS-части), могу предположить, что кроме значения **plus**, есть еще значение аля **minus**. В каждом случае, есть свои ajax-запросы (идентичные по сути!) и свои обработчики, которые также выполняют абсолютно одинаковые действия, с той лишь принципиальной разницей, что в первом случае, значение поля **golosov** увеличивается на единицу, а во втором - уменьшается.

**-** Продолжая разбор полета в части **ajax** - что вы хотите получит в ответе? И какой тип данных вы хотите получить?! Кроме

```
echo 'Вы уже голосовали за данный комментарий! Голосовать можно только один раз!';
```

я ничего не наблюдаю. Можно было бы предположить, что вам так и надо, если бы вы не говорили о том, что проблема как раз и состоит в том, что результат не виден сразу, а хотелось бы ... я так думаю )) **Кстати, а какой результат вы бы хотели видеть?!**

---

Я наверняка не знаю каких-то определенных нюансов, но, пропустив тонкости, попробую определить задачу так:

> При нажатии на кнопку **+** или **-**, необходимо соответственно увеличить/уменьшить количество голосов (в БД), отданных за определенную статью и вывести конечный результат пользователю - итоговое количество голосов по данной статье.

Предлагаю попробовать так:

**JS** (объединим обработку голосования)

```
$(function() {
    $('.vote').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var articleId = $(this).attr('id'); // ID статьи
        var voteValue = $(this).attr('name'); // голос "ЗА" или "ПРОТИВ"
        var parent = $(this);

        $(this).fadeIn(200).html('<img src="/images/upload.gif" align="absmiddle">');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/pages/handler_vote.php',
            data: {aid: articleId, vVal: voteValue},
            success: function(data){
                // в data[0] - значение $success
                // в data[1] - значение $response
                if(data[0]){
                    parent.html(data[1]);
                } else {
                    alert(data[1]);
                }
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    });
});
```

**PHP** (!один обработчик *handler_vote.php*)

```
if(isset($_POST['aid'])){
    // Проверку на "право голоса" и последний запрос (INSERT) сделаете сами

    if(/* если права голоса нет */){
        $response = 'Вы уже голосовали за данный комментарий! Голосовать можно только один раз!';
        $success = false;
    } else {
        $aid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['aid']);
        $voteValue = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['vVal']);
        // Вместо проверки ниже, можно значения "1" и "-1" хранить вместо "plus" и "minus" в атрибуте "name"
        if($voteValue == 'plus'){
            $vote = 1;
        } else {
            $vote = -1;
        }
        // Увеличиваем или уменьшаем кол-во голосов
        $resUpd = mysql_query("UPDATE `articles_comments` SET `golosov` = `golosov` + '".$vote."' WHERE `id` = '".$aid."'");
        // Проверку на то, что проапдейтилось или нет - на ваше усмотрение
        if($resUpd){
            $resSel = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `articles_comments` WHERE `id`='".$aid."'");
            $articles = mysql_fetch_assoc($resSel);
            /* что-то еще делаете свое */
            $response = $articles['golosov']; // Итоговое количество голосов
            $success = true;
        } else {
            $response = 'Хьюстон! У нас проблемы!!! Апдейт потерян!';
            $success = false;
        }
    }
    // Подготавливаем ответ
    echo json_encode(array($success,$response));
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Часть вопросов лишнее. 
Это if($row['id_user']==$user['id'] && $user['level']<2 && $articles['pobeda']==0)
{
echo 'Вы уже голосовали за данный комментарий! Голосовать можно только один раз!';
exit;
} просто ниже опустить.
Хотел бы сразу видеть результат голосования. На странице комментариев он выводится так: echo '<span>'.$all_rat_comments.'</span>'; В общем подсчитывается ко-во отрицательных, положительных отзывов, от кол-ва положительных отнимаем кол-во отрицательных и выводим. В поле golosov пишется общее кол-во голосов за коммент (прибавляется или отнимается) для сортировки комментариев.

Comment: Так то работает, только немного кое-что дописал. Но было бы не плохо сделать удаление кол-ва голосов, т.к. оно выводится и удаления ссылки на минус если голосую положительно и наоборот. И почему=то все равно по 2 голоса прибавляется/отнимается.
И кстати про ИД - $id = isset ($_REQUEST['id']) ? abs(intval($_REQUEST['id'])) : false;

Comment: У вас итак в вопросе много чего не понятного было, а сейчас еще больше загадок стало.

Задача у вас, по сути, простейшая, но вы как-то умудрились ее усложнить. Могу предположить, что часть проблем всплывает из-за не правильно спроектированной структуры БД, проблема *все равно по 2 голоса прибавляется/отнимается* - может быть из-за не правильной последовательности выполнений операций в скрипте. Гадать, что и почему, можно долго.

Comment: @vitagame, уходите от mysql_* в сторону PDO,MySQLi etc.

Comment: Да надо бы.